# Datatables Sort within rows selected

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table that has multiple number of entries(rows) 5-10-50-ALL available to a user.

I would like to be able to sort only the columns pertaining to the actual number of rows showing instead of it sorted the entire table. 
For example? 
Total table length is 50 rows. Initial load is 5 rows. When I click on that column I only want it to sort based on those 5 rows not the entire 50.

Is that even possible?

```
    SELECT m1.number, m1.incident_id, DATEADD(hh,8,m1.update_time)update_time, DATEADD(hh,8,m1.open_Time)open_time, m1.assignment, o1.full_name
              FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1 left outer join operatorm1 o1 on m1.assignee_name = o1.name
              WHERE status not in('closed','resolved')
              AND category <> 'event'
              Order By open_time
```

Comment: Some code? What did you try? The answer is Yes it is possible.

Comment: Hi bksi. I havn't tried anything. To be honest I wouldn't even know where to start

Comment: Hm. first you can post the table select query. This is good start

Comment: The ORDER BY clause doesn't afects LIMIT clause on SQL. So you just put query like: SELECT columns FROM tablename WHERE yourwhere ORDER BY yourColumn LIMIT 0,5;

Comment: How you get exactly 5 rows?

Comment: Add LIMIT 0,5 at the end of your query and when you have second, third, and so on page change 0 with ($page-1)*5

Comment: Maybe I am not making my point clear.. I get 5 rows by limiting the jquery datatable. Basically the query pulls all the data 300+ rows but the table only shows 5 at a time..but the sorting is not working for each subset of rows.

Comment: it is not good idea to get all rows from the table and then work with them